# Order item with persistent custom field value

Tags: 8, views, commerce

#### Goal

With Drupal Commerce, my goal is to have a customizable product with persistent user entered text.

I have added a text field to the order item type and I can see the custom field in the "add to cart" form. When customer enters a value in that field and adds the product to the cart, I can see the value of that field in the cart form view.

I want to have a link to the purchased entity in the cart form view so I checked "Link label to the referenced entity" in the view field configuration.

When I hit that link, I get back to my product page, with the correct variation selected, but the custom text field will be empty.

#### Question

How can I make this custom text field persistent, that is, "save" its value so that when I click the item link in the cart view, I get back to the product variation with the custom text field already filled in?

*Note: I could have multiple products/variations in the cart, each with a different custom text so I need to keep the value on the order item level.*

#### What I have tried

I thought about having that custom text field value as a parameter in the cart form view purchased entity link URL so I tried to rewrite the output of that field/link, but I don't have access to the product entity from that view and I'd need it to compute the new URL... so that won't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a more elegant way but this works for me.

First I rebuild the purchased entity link in the commerce cart form view to include the custom text field value as a parameter in the link URL for when I navigate back from the cart to the product variation:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view_field().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {

  $view = $variables['view'];
  $field = $variables['field'];

  // Commerce cart form
  if (isset($view) && ($view->id() === 'commerce_cart_form')) {

    switch($field->field) {
      case 'purchased_entity':

        // Get purchased entity
        $purchased_entity = $variables['row']->_relationship_entities['order_items']->purchased_entity->getValue();
        $purchased_entity_id = $purchased_entity[0]['target_id'];

        // Load product variation
        $product_variation = $variation = ProductVariation::load($purchased_entity_id);

        // Get product variation URL
        $url = Url::fromUserInput($product_variation->toLink()->getUrl()->toString());

        // Get custom field value
        $custom_field = $variables['row']->_relationship_entities['order_items']->field_custom->getValue();

        // Rebuild url with variation & custom field value
        $url->setOption('query', [
          'v' => $purchased_entity_id,
          'custom' => $custom_field[0]['value'],
        ]);

        // Output
        $variables['output'] = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t($product_variation->label()), $url);

        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This will output a link like `/product/1?v=2&custom=MYVALUE`

And then on the product add to cart form, if the param is in the URL, I set the default value of the custom field:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_commerce_product_') !== false) {

    // Set custom text form field value from URL
    $form['field_custom']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = \Drupal::request()->query->get('custom');
  }
}
```